# Saving data from a form to table

Tags: ms-access, vba

This is baffling me.

I have a userform with a listbox showing everything in my table (connected using rowsource)

On my form I have combo boxes and text boxes, when a user updates them I want the data to overwrite whats in the table.

When they click an account in the list box the text/combo boxes populate the data, when they change come data it simply does not save and I don't know why.

On the text/combo boxes I have the following code to save in the table:

```
    RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
DoCmd.DoMenuItem acFormBar, acRecordsMenu, acSaveRecord, , acMenuVer70
Me.Refresh
Me.Dirty = False
```

Any idea why some wont save?

Comment: Nothing needed. A bound form will automatically update when you move to another record or close the form.

Comment: In your combo box and text boxes, you say you have the rowsource populated, but have you placed any of the table's fields in the control sources?

Comment: Do you mean have I bound the text boxes etc to the table? If so, yeah I have done that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an alternative code to the one you have

```
Dim db As Database
Dim rec As Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM <<Insert Table Name>> WHERE <<TextBox>>= Primary Key")

rec.Edit

rec("<<Table Field Name>>") = Me.<<Form textbox etc>>
rec("<<Table Field Name>>") = Me.<<Form textbox etc>>

rec.AddNew
```